# Reduce the line length of the strike through within the \neq sign

Tags: math-mode

I am convinced this is a duplicate as much as I used a search engine to unsuccessfully find one, but how can I control the line length of the `\neq` symbol please? I do not want to use `tikz` and I am sure there would be a way with kerning but I am not sure how to manipulate math symbols, should they be overlayed on top?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$P\neq x^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

I do not like how far the diagonal strike through travels and would like a way to control it using the centre of the equal line as the origin if possible please so it is equal in length on both sides. How can this be achieved please? Would appreciate a duplicate if this is not original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\neqA{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{.7pt}{\vstretch{.5}{/}}{=}}}}
\begin{document}
$P\neq x^2$

$P\neqA x^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a version that allows script math styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\neqA{\mathrel{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{.8\LMpt-.1pt}{%
  \SavedStyle\vstretch{.5}{/}}{\SavedStyle=}}}}}
\begin{document}
$P\neq x^2$

$P\neqA x^2$

$\scriptstyle P\neqA x^2$

$\scriptscriptstyle P\neqA x^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use a slash in the relative script size.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\smallnot}{}{\mathrel{\text{\smallnot@}}}

\newcommand{\smallnot@}{%
  \settowidth\dimen@{$\m@th=$}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \makebox[\dimen@]{%
      $\m@th\vcenter{\hbox{\fontsize{\sf@size}{0}\selectfont$/$}}$%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy{\oldnot}{\not}% Just for comparison
  \RenewCommandCopy{\not}{\smallnot}%
}

\begin{document}

$\not= \neq \ne$\quad
$\scriptstyle\not= \neq \ne$\quad
$\scriptscriptstyle\not= \neq \ne$

$\oldnot=$

\end{document}
```

It doesn't work so well in scriptscript size, but I don't think it's a real problem.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In OpTeX, you can use `\mathbox` which keeps the actual textsize/scriptsize etc.

```
\fontfam[lm]

\def\neq{\mathrel{\mathbox{\setfontsize{mag.7}\rm\raise.2ex\rlap{\kern.25em/}}{=}}}

defined: $a \neq b_{\neq}$

original: $a \ne b_{\ne}$

\bye
```